# Arduino: Using multiple inputs in same time

Tags: arduino

i'm working on simple car steering so i've made 2 buttons for forward/backward and 2  buttons for left/right steering. I have 2 LEDs to just see how it works but it doesn't work how i like to. I can only use one button i one time, so while moving forward i wont be able to move left/right etc. How to do this? Here's my code in IDE:

```
   int LED = 12;
   int LED2 = 2;
   int ButtonUP = 9;
   int ButtonDOWN = 7;
   int ButtonLEFT = 4;
   int ButtonRIGHT = 8;

   int sygnalUP = 0;
   int sygnalDOWN = 0;
   int sygnalLEFT = 0;
   int sygnalRIGHT = 0;

 void setup() {
pinMode (LED, OUTPUT);
pinMode (ButtonUP, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode (ButtonDOWN, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode (ButtonLEFT, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode (ButtonRIGHT, INPUT_PULLUP);
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("     |GORA|DOL|LEW|PRA");
}

 void loop() {
 int buttonUPst = digitalRead(ButtonUP);
 int buttonDOWNst = digitalRead(ButtonDOWN);
 int buttonLEFTst = digitalRead(ButtonLEFT);
 int buttonRIGHTst = digitalRead(ButtonRIGHT);


 if (buttonUPst == LOW) {
 digitalWrite(12, HIGH); 
 sygnalUP = 1;
 Serial.print("Sygnal: ");
 Serial.print(sygnalUP);
 Serial.print(" | ");
 Serial.print(sygnalDOWN);
 Serial.print(" | ");
 Serial.print(sygnalLEFT);
 Serial.print(" | ");
 Serial.println(sygnalRIGHT);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(12, LOW);
 sygnalUP = 0;
 }

 if (buttonDOWNst == LOW) {
 digitalWrite(12, HIGH); 
 sygnalDOWN = 1;
 Serial.print("Sygnal: ");
 Serial.print(sygnalUP);
 Serial.print(" | ");
 Serial.print(sygnalDOWN);
 Serial.print(" | ");
 Serial.print(sygnalLEFT);
 Serial.print(" | ");
 Serial.println(sygnalRIGHT);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(12, LOW);
 sygnalDOWN = 0;
 }

 if (buttonLEFTst == LOW) {
 digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH); 
 sygnalLEFT = 1;
 Serial.print("Sygnal: ");
 Serial.print(sygnalUP);
 Serial.print(" | ");
 Serial.print(sygnalDOWN);
 Serial.print(" | ");
 Serial.print(sygnalLEFT);
 Serial.print(" | ");
 Serial.println(sygnalRIGHT);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
 sygnalLEFT = 0;
 }

 if (buttonRIGHTst == LOW) {
 digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH); 
 sygnalRIGHT = 1;
 Serial.print("Sygnal: ");
 Serial.print(sygnalUP);
 Serial.print(" | ");
 Serial.print(sygnalDOWN);
 Serial.print(" | ");
 Serial.print(sygnalLEFT);
 Serial.print(" | ");
 Serial.println(sygnalRIGHT);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
 sygnalRIGHT = 0;
 }
}
```

As you can see i've made code to see how inputs work in serial, it looks like this:

> ```
>      |GORA|DOL|LEW|PRA
> Sygnal: 1 | 0 | 0 | 0
> Sygnal: 1 | 0 | 0 | 0
> Sygnal: 1 | 0 | 0 | 0
> Sygnal: 1 | 0 | 0 | 0
> Sygnal: 0 | 1 | 0 | 0
> Sygnal: 0 | 1 | 0 | 0
> Sygnal: 0 | 1 | 0 | 0
> Sygnal: 0 | 1 | 0 | 0
> Sygnal: 0 | 0 | 1 | 0
> ```

And here you can see also that i can't make to have two "1" abreast. I know I'm making basic mistake here but my knownledge is pretty poor. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is not C .And format/indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there!

You're printing the `Sygnal` values in the table, but the individual `if` blocks as-are are guaranteeing only one of those is true at a time.  But the `button` values you read at the beginning of each loop can be simultaneously `LOW`.  So you might do something like the following:

- Just update the `Sygnal` values once per `loop()` according to the `button` values (as well as the corresponding `digitalWrite()`s.
- Use only one `delay()` when asserting the multiple `digitalWrite()`s.
- If you still want to print the `Sygnal` values, just print them once at the end of `loop()`.

Edit: Here's a modified `loop()` along the above lines.  Hope this helps.

```
void printStates() {
  Serial.print("Sygnal: ");
  Serial.print(sygnalUP);
  Serial.print(" | ");
  Serial.print(sygnalDOWN);
  Serial.print(" | ");
  Serial.print(sygnalLEFT);
  Serial.print(" | ");
  Serial.println(sygnalRIGHT); 
  Serial.flush(); // block execution for as long as needed to print row
}

void loop() {
  int buttonUPst = digitalRead(ButtonUP);
  int buttonDOWNst = digitalRead(ButtonDOWN);
  int buttonLEFTst = digitalRead(ButtonLEFT);
  int buttonRIGHTst = digitalRead(ButtonRIGHT);

  if (buttonUPst == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH); 
    sygnalUP = 1;
  } else {
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW); 
    sygnalUP = 0;
  }

  // ...Repeat above if-else for other three button directions here...

  printStates();
}
```